# I want to add post meta for picture thum during submit for revision

Tags: plugin-development

I am using this function to get imnages urls from google

```
   function getGoogleImg($k)
{
    $url = "http://images.google.com/images?as_q=##query##&hl=it&imgtbs=z&btnG=Cerca+con+Google&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&imgtype=&imgsz=m&imgw=&imgh=&imgar=&as_filetype=&imgc=&as_sitesearch=&as_rights=&safe=images&as_st=y";
    $web_page = file_get_contents( str_replace("##query##",urlencode($k), $url ));
    $tieni = stristr($web_page,"dyn.setResults(");
    $tieni = str_replace( "dyn.setResults(","", str_replace(stristr($tieni,");"),"",$tieni) );
    $tieni = str_replace("[]","",$tieni);
    $m = preg_split("/[\[\]]/",$tieni);
    $x = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($m);$i++)
    {
        $m[$i] = str_replace("/imgres?imgurl\\x3d","",$m[$i]);
        $m[$i] = str_replace(stristr($m[$i],"\\x26imgrefurl"),"",$m[$i]);
        $m[$i] = preg_replace("/^\"/i","",$m[$i]);
        $m[$i] = preg_replace("/^,/i","",$m[$i]);
        if ($m[$i]!="")
        array_push($x,$m[$i]);
   }
   return $x;
}
```

After that i want add image url to post meta i am using this function to add post meta

```
  function add_image_to_save_post($post_ID)
    {
            if ( !wp_is_post_revision($post_id) )
        {
        $title = $_POST['post_title'];
        $image = getGoogleImg ($title);
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'thumb', $image[3], true);

        }
    }
    add_action('wp_insert_post', 'add_image_to_save_post');
```

But when i click on on link add new post its add autmatically blank thumb key in database

I just want this for users so just add articles they no need to add image to article image will fetch automatically,

Can anyone give me suggestion how this possible

Thanks

MOhammad Umer

Comment: I don't understand the need for `global $post; $pos_id = $post->ID;`, besides the `$pos_id` being an unused variable afterwards I don't think `global $post` contains anything at that point, you already have the `$post_ID` from the action, what do you need `global $post;` for?

Comment: ok i will remove them

Comment: But still getting empty thumb after click on add new post

Comment: is there any action when user click on "post submit for review" this button then fetch thumb key

Comment: Hold on, are you changing the post status to "Pending Review"? Can you add `die('Trying to get image...');` at the very top of your function to see if it's even called? Also modify your question to reflect the current code you're working with, please.

Comment: thanks i have changed the code. i am waiting for your code please thanks

Comment: What code? Is your hook even pulled, i.e. does the `add_image_to_save_post` execute?

Comment: yes that function add_image_to_save_post is called what hook even pulled

Comment: do you have skype? if have please add me at umershaikh79 so we can solve this metter online. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your current setup, you can see that your `add_image_to_save_post` function is fired off when `wp_insert_post` is performed.

`wp_insert_post` is fired off when a post is inserted into the database, and as you may know, as soon as you click "Add New" in WordPress a database entry is created, thus pulling on your hook.

What happens next is `$title = $_POST['post_title'];`, and yet there is no `post_title`, so `getGoogleImg()` is called with `NULL`, thus, I assume that the `$web_page` is not populated with what you would expect.

WordPress offers a set of actions that are useful when a post is saved, edited and even has its status changed. In your case, posts are premoderated for users, meaning that they cannot publish and can only set the status to `pending`. And there are actions for status changes: `draft_to_pending`, `draft_to_publish`, `pending_to_publish`, `publish_to_private`, etc. its always in the form of `status_to_status`.

So hopefully, changing the hook to fire off on `draft_to_pending` will solve your problem.

And on a completely different note, it's not good to use non-validated user-input  from `$_POST['post_title']`, who knows what kind of things the user will write there, and will result in directory-traversal and XSS in your case. So try to grab it from the `post` instead, you have the `$post_ID`, get it using `get_post($post_ID)` and then grab its `post_title` from there.

Hope this helped.